# sqlserver update a fix column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

Table ta has column as below：

a,b,c

and then i add column d to table ta (column d's value reply on code below to generate)

```
select a+'-'+ rtrim(b) +'-'+ cast(row_number() over(order by a) as varchar) +'-tanew' as d  from main
```

i tried to insert into ,but it will cover the exsits-value in column a,b,c . how do i do to keep the original data of a,b,c and insert into d like the code show above?

thanks a lot!

**here's final solution of my case:**

```
update ta set d = [a] +'-' + rtrim([b]) + [c] + '-tanew'
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Comment: If you just want to fill the new column, you should not insert, but update.

Comment: how to write the where statement in sql code? if i wanna update each line ?thx

Answer (score 0):

if youre using ssms, try :::

```
alter table main
add d varchar(max)
update main
set d =
(select a+'-'+ rtrim(b) +'-'+ cast(row_number() over(order by a) as varchar) +'-tanew'  from main )

--i assume col a and b are already in varchar format
```

Comment: add brackets to the last select will extinct the grammar error . also can not use this way ,becos the select 's return value is not monodromy. i will consider  the  CURSOR?

Comment: ,thanks a lot ,plz check the question body ,left the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create and update a column with `row_number` value.
It's hard for maintenance this column when you insert or delete rows or update column `a`

Just use a view

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourViewName AS
(
   SELECT *,
       concat(a,'-', b,'-', row_number() over(ORDER BY Name)) AS d 
 FROM dbo.YourTable t
)
```

And select data

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.YourViewName vt
```

Note:

- `Row_number` is only used in `order by` or `select` clause
- If you are
  using SQL 2012+, you could use `concat` for sum strings.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (a + '-' + rtrim(b) + '-' + cast(row_number() over (order by a) as varchar(255)) + '-tanew'
             ) as new_d 
      from main
     )
update toupdate
    set d = new_d;
```

Note:  Whenever you use `varchar()`, you should *always* include a length.  SQL Server defaults the length to different values based on the context.  Bugs that arise from such defaults are quite hard to debug.